# Проверка на вхождение в массив интов

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

Здравствуйте. Есть массив целых чисел.

```
int[] list_line_num = new int[6] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

И есть DataRow взятый из DataTable.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
```

Мне нужно проверить входит ли 1 из элементов row в этот массив.
Делаю вот такими вот способами. Не один не получился. Что я делаю не так. Хотя бы 1 из способов объясните пожалуйста. А лучше если можно то все.

```
list_line_num.Contains(row["workplace_id"])

Array.Exists(list_line_num, element => element.StartsWith())
```

Ко второму способу 2 вопроса. Во первых у меня у элемента нет атрибута StartsWith, возможно какую то библиотечку не подключил. Подскажите какую нужно. И что в моём случае нужно поместить в StartsWith если я просто хочу узнать входит ли циферка которая извлекается из row в мой массив.

Comment: row["workplace_id"] имеет целый тип? Как его можно искать в массиве Int?

Comment: Второй способ использует LINQ

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka в первом случае добавил конверт в int32 вроде нет ошибок чуть позже подебажу. Линк подключил всё равно нет StartsWith

Comment: StartsWith функция String

Answer (score 2):

Индексатор класса `DataTable` возвращает object. Ваш `List` содержит `int`'ы. Соответственно, вам надо преобразовать значения интересующего столбца в int и искать в массиве уже это значение. В `DataTable` есть соответствующий метод `Field<T>`:

```
list_line_num.Contains(row.Field<int>("workplace_id"));
```

При условии, что столбец содержит только целочисленные значения и не содержит `null`,  можно также использовать любой метод парсинга целых чисел: `Convert.ToInt32`,  `int.Parse` или `int.TryParse`

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.Exists(ist_line_num, element => element == row["workplace_id"])
```